# ElasticSearch : constant_score query vs function_score query

Tags: elasticsearch, computer-science, distributed-system, aws-elasticsearch, opensearch

I recently upgraded my ElasticSearch version from version 5.3 to version 5.6

```
 "query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "terms" : {
              "customerId" : [ "ASERFE", "7004567457" ]
            }
          },
          "must_not" : {
            "terms" : {
              "useCase" : [ "PAY", "COLLECT" ]
            }
          }
        },
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "match" : {
               "cardProductGroupName" : {
                  "query" : "Pre-fill Test birthday Present",
                  "type" : "phrase"
                }
             }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

executing the query mentioned above gave me the following error -

> {"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[constant_score] query does not support [query]","line":1,"col":37}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"[constant_score] query does not support [query]","line":1,"col":37}

So, I searched for the solution and found this function_score query. On executing the query mentioned below I am getting the same results that I would have got with constant_score.

```
"query" : {
    "function_score" : {
      "query" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "terms" : {
              "customerId" : [ "ASERFE", "7004567457" ]
            }
          },
          "must_not" : {
            "terms" : {
              "useCase" : [ "PAY", "COLLECT" ]
            }
          }
        },
         "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "match" : {
               "groupName" : {
                  "query" : "Pre-fill Test birthday Present",
                  "type" : "phrase"
                }
             }
          }
        }
      },
      "functions" : [ {
        "script_score" : {
          "script" : "1"
        }
      } ],
      "boost_mode" : "replace"
    }
  }
```

so my question is, Does it implies that function_score with script : "1" would give same result as constant_function ?

Answer (score 0):

It will give the same result indeed though performance might be worse if it will still run the "script" for each matching document.

On the other hand, `constant_score` [still exists in 5.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html) though you have to use `filter`+`boost` instead of `query`.

Comment: Thanks @ilvar for your answer, using `constant_score` with `filter`+`boost` is certainly a correct solution. but my query has `matchPhraseQuery` and as far as I know Filter Query doesn't support something like matchQuery inside filter. Hence, I can't go for the same. Is there any alternative of `match` query that I can use with filter inside constant_score.

Comment: Have you tried it? I don't have 5.6 at hand but I think in 5.x it should be possible to use queries in filter contexts...